# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::filter()

Tags: php, laravel

I try to make Filters.

When I have:

```
    public function index(OrderFilter $filter): View
    {
        $items = Order::withTrashed()->filter($filter)->paginate(10);

        return view($this->viewsPath . self::INDEX_ACTION, [
            'items' => $items,
            'perPage' => 10,
        ]);
    }
```

I take mistake `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::filter()`

But when I delete `filter($filter)` I have not any mistake but my filtration does not work.

How can I make filtration correctly?

OrderFilter

```
<?php

namespace App\Filters\Orders;

use App\Filters\QueryFilter;

class OrderFilter extends QueryFilter
{
    public function id(string $id)
    {
        $this->builder->where('id', $id);
    }

    public function name(string $name)
    {
        $this->builder->where('name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%');
    }

    public function address(string $address)
    {
        $this->builder->where('address', 'like', '%' . $address . '%');
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `$filter` exactly contain?

Comment: Also `->filter()` would work on collection objects.

Comment: @aleksandr, you need to import the namespace in the current file

Comment: At the point when you use `filter($filter)` you have a instance of the QueryBuilder instead of the Collection class. `filter()` is a collection method. For the QueryBuilder you have all the `where` conditions and more. Check the docs.

Comment: I don't know why but I am using the filter in a similar way in another class and don't have any errors

Comment: We need to SEE OrderFilter otherwise responses are pure speculation

Comment: I added OrderFilter

Comment: where would you have defined this `filter` method?

Answer (score 0):

filter() is a method that is available on collections. So when you do

```
$query = Order::withTrashed()->filter($filter)->paginate(10);
```

what you are doing is appending the filter method to the query builder instance and this will give you error.

In order to fix this, you can do:

```
$query = Order::withTrashed()->paginate(10)->filter($filter);
```

and, this won't give you error because now you're applying filters on the collection.

Comment: Then I have ```Illuminate\Support\Collection::filter(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be of type ?callable, App\Filters\Orders\OrderFilter given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php on line 23```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to conditionally apply filters by modifying the query builder, maybe consider the [EloquentFilter package by Tucker-Eric](https://github.com/Tucker-Eric/EloquentFilter).